# How to add noise signal to a sinusoidal signal with a specified ratio of dB in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to add a noise signal to a signal which is a combination of three sinusoidal signals with different amplitude, frequency and phase. How to add this noise signal to the sinusoidal signal so that the Signal-to-Noise ratio will be 10 dB?? and how to pass this resulting signal through an averaging filter (low pass filter system)??

Comment: i know @knedlsepp i saw that post, but i want the signal to noise ratio be specified and pass the resulting signal through a filter. so it's quite different that's why i posted it :)

Comment: No, it's not different at all. You are asking A+B, whereas the linked question gives you A, and there's probably lots of other questions about filtering, which will give you B.

Answer (score 0):

For sinusoid with amplitude A : SignalPower=0.5*A^2
For white gaussian noise with STDV=q and Bandwidth=BW: NoisePower=BW*q^2

So for your signal: SNR=(0.5*A1^2+0.5*A2^2+0.5*A3^2)/(BW*q^2)

In matlab you create gaussian white noise with sigma=q:

```
Noise=q*randn(1,SignalLength);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer dude, but i didn't really get it. i have to combine three sinusoidal signals as below:
 a - first signal, Amplitude = 10, frequency = 200 Hz, phase = pi/4,

       b - second signal, Amplitude = 15, frequency = 2000 Hz, phase = pi/8,

       c - Third signal, Amplitude = 25, frequency = 2800 Hz, phase = pi/2,

i have to add the noise to the resulting signal of these three signals.
so what will be the "q" and "BW" in this case??
thank you again